# authorized_keys and with_items in Ansible

Tags: ssh-keys, ansible

I'm trying to create new users and populate their ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file using Ansible. Here's my task:

```
- name: Create user account
  user: name="{{ item.username }}-ns" comment="{{ item.realname }}"
    groups=adm,sudo, append=yes
    password="{{ item.password }}"
  with_items: "{{ ssh_users }}"
- name: copy ssh keys to authorized_keys
  authorized_key:  user="{{ item.username }}-ns"
    key="{{ sshkey_path }}/{{ item.username }}.pub"
  with_item: "{{ ssh_users }}"
```

and my variables file looks like this:

```
ssh_users:
  - username: "jdoe"
    realname: "jrow"
    password: "$6$FWhXrnkizCqwKJcM$y55ETlvthHA49NuzwYgKAmOTnsBDRzfXE1OiOuJ.HHwVuI4P/BQrR/eKgYOioevIrgYYw.HpeP/sxCR3M38SW/"
  - username: "jroe"
    realname: "Jane Roe"
    password: "$6$wQhvxq3C.egKzrGi$na0M4jn3bi1lM2dz2YvdbAvvJBvbg4iGH1K6j7sHnZZt7mZggexHPvxOT799pfaDKmU6xDrbtbrLsxviGyABA0"
  - username: "testuser"
    realname: "Test User"
    password: "$6$U24oz4dsfdYD/LZ$fuziBEkc2q/POHSEvfcuTaD6wFTF.49RbU8z8JLQk3oki/He87cYqpSZtL16A11EBaG6VdemXdy6\V/"
```

I've setup the various user's public ssh keys into a publickeys directory which I put in the variable named "sshkey_path".  There is one public key file for each user (e.g. jdoe.pub).

When I run the playbook, the user account creation goes fine, but the authorized_keys part says:

```
ERROR! 'with_item' is not a valid attribute for a Task

The error appears to have been in 'user-add.yaml': line 29, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: copy ssh keys to authorized_keys
      ^ here
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?  In principle, it should work as there are [similar examples](https://brokenbad.com/better-handling-of-public-ssh-keys-using-ansible/) found online.  I've played with the format but cannot get it to work.  Your pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is failing, is because the actual plugin is called [with_items](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html) and not with_item. You forgot the s.

Comment: Oh my. You're right. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

For posterity:

Along with the mistake pointed out by "linuxdynasty" regarding `with_items`, there was a further error in the way I was referencing the key file.

I tried to use the following syntax:

```
key="{{ sshkey_path }}/{{ item.username }}.pub"
```

But that won't work in this case because `authroized_key` expects a file. One must either use "with_files" or Lookups to get this.

To make it work in my situation, I had to concatenate multiple variables together, which I did with the help of this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610904/using-variables-for-file-name-and-file-contents-in-lineinfile-module) post.  The final syntax I came up with was:

```
key="{{ lookup('file', sshkey_path+item.username+'.pub') }}"
```

and it worked fine.